# Does excel provide a method for sorting columns based on numbers and phrases contained within one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, sorting

I receive a packet of data in the form of a .csv file from our database manager. I import this data into excel for formatting and sorting. However, one column contains three pieces of info that I want to parse and sort. A single cell in this column consists of a user ID number, and a user name
(for example: "83920 - johndavis") I want to be able to sort this column based off of each of these terms. Is this possible using macros in Excel or should I use VBA, and if so how do you suggest approaching this problem?

I have a background in C and python so despite a limited VBA knowledge I have computer science experience.

Here is some info I collected while experimenting with solutions. This page was my starting point: https://www.cedarville.edu/insights/blog/excel-how-to-parse-data-split-column-into-multiple.aspx
However, when I attempted to use this method, the column split encountered errors and didn't split properly (see pictures). I believe this is because the column data is actual data manipulated in VBA from another page of the excel sheet. How would you go about resolving that idiosyncrasy?

[Data as seen from the function bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Apwv.png)

[Page 1 of the Column Split Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoOOT.png)

[Page 2 of the Column Split Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbWB7.png)

[Page 3 of the Column Split Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnm8q.png)

[Incorrect Column Split Wizard Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpXVA.png)

Comment: I believe text to columns only works on the data in the cells, not on the results of formulas. Use `=LEFT(data,FIND(delimiter,data,1)-1)` in one column to get the data before the delimiter then use `=MID(data,FIND(delimiter,data,1)+LEN(delimiter),LEN(data))` to get the data after the delimiter.

Comment: Awesome, this is a potentially very succinct solution! I'll let you know how it works.My only question is where should the column delimiter definitions go? I am not a very experienced excel user so I'm uncertain.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Macros are written in VBA and based on ur title and experience I'd say give VBA a try its super useful

Answer (score 2):

That's a rather weird CSV as it contains Excel formulas. It's not expected that a CSV contains anything else than data.

Currently the cell doesn't just have the data value `B09 - Theater`, but it has the formula:

```
=IFERROR(@__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("""COMPUTED_VALUE"""), "B09 - Theater")
```

The [IFERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) formula evaluates the (dummy) function `@__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("""COMPUTED_VALUE""")` and if that returns an error, it writes the value `B09 - Theater`.

If you don't need to maintain those formulas (I don't know if they serve a purpose) and just need the data the easiest would be to select all cells and [paste them in a new sheet as **values**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/paste-options-8ea795b0-87cd-46af-9b59-ed4d8b1669ad).

After that you can use [the answer of iskyfire](https://superuser.com/a/1569225/141595).

Comment: Some clarification: I import as .csv that is simply rows and columns of raw data, no formulas or funkiness. The sheet I import them into is a function excel sheet that we use to speed up the formatting of the CSV. The VBA exists within that sheet to do mass reformatting automatically. The formulas are important as pages further down the sheet function order rely on them.

Answer (score 2):

Per my comment to your post, you can do this instead:

[image]

I would also note that your image showing a reference to a VBA function prefixed with `@__xludf.` likely means that the function is not available to the current workbook. It may be in a different module on another workbook, or in an unavailable library.

Regardless, in simple cases with part1*delimiter*part2, you can use the formulas above.

In more complex cases, you can select any cell in your data and use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range to start a PowerQuery.

Within the Power Query Editor, you can select the column you want to split and use Home> Transform>Split Column>By Delimiter and configure it like this (for example):

[image]

The output looks like this:
[image]

You could then use Home>Close & Load to load the results back to the workbook.

Comment: Is it possible that @__xludf. is a function exclusive to GSheets? That is where this sheet was imported from. I switched to excel to use the column wizard and now I'm wondering if I should switch back. The rest of this method I will attempt shortly.

Comment: When attempting your simple case, I encountered a Invalid Name Error that stated '"This formula contains unrecognized text" in the cell where I pasted the formulas (aligned to how you had in the images. I will try the power query method now

Comment: Yes, it could be a Sheets function. If the function is not available in the current workbook, when you try to calculate the sheet it will not work, and you'll run into problems.  You may want to Paste Special>Values before continuing in Excel. In Sheets, the LEFT and MID functions should work fine as well.

Comment: PowerQuery method: it split the data perfectly and placed it in a new sheet. However I was hoping it would place the data in the columns adjacent to the column highlighted. It also appended more than a million rows to the bottom of the new sheet. This can likely be done with Macros but I was wondering if I had made an error.

Comment: Power Query will always load the results to a new sheet. If you want it to stay in place, use Paste Special>Values on the formula column before using the LEFT and MID functions as described above. Similarly, after Paste Special>Values, you'll be able to use Text To Columns without trouble, which will handle more complex cases. Just make sure you have enough empty columns to the right of the column you're going to split.

Comment: Okay thank you. You may have provided me with the solution I needed! I will update the OP if I succeed

Comment: Oh! Is there a way for Power Query to create a new sheet but with no color coding or formatting, just the data? It's one extra step to wipe out the formatting but it would be nice to just skip it.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that without VBA unfortunately. In case it helps... Alt, J, T, S, C will clear the formatting from a formatted table.

Comment: Do you know if google sheets has a power query equivalent? I will have to rewrite the VBA between sheets for it to work properly with excel if that is not that case, plus excel licenses are expensive

Comment: I don't think so. But it does have text-to-columns. Data menu, I think. You can specify a custom delimiter like " - "

Comment: @FlexYourData If you use the `Close and Load To...` option when exiting PQ, you will have the option of loading results to same sheet.

Comment: Yes, but you can't write it to the same location as the source.

Answer (score 1):

## Convert Text into Columns

If you have a cell that contains multiple data values, you can separate them using the built-in Convert Text to Columns Wizard. This will create a table with 1 data value per column which will enable you to use all the filters and sorting methods that are available with excel.

**Note:** If you have multiple unique delimiters separating each data value, for example `83920/johndavis - new york city` you can use find and replace to change all of the `-` characters into `/` or vice versa. You need to have the same delimiter separating each data value or you will need to run the wizard multiple times.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7 for additional information.

## Removing Extraneous Functions

If the data that you have is encapsulated, you can use Find and Replace with `Match entire cell contents` checked and `Look in: Formulas` selected.

Select the range, go into Find and Replace, make your entries and Replace All. For Example `=IFERROR(@__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("""COMPUTED_VALUE"""),"` to an empty string.

Then you can run it again to remove the ending part `")` to an empty string.

Ensure that before making large-scale find and replace operations, you have backed up the original copy of the worksheet.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the info. Check out my edit, I tried your method and encountered errors that I think are related to the page to page vba implementation.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a method that will allow you to extract plain text from the columns.

Comment: All very helpful. I will try this and let you know the results!

Comment: I used find and replace to highlight the text but what should I put in the "find" box? Currently replacing does nothing when I click "find and replace".